# Warranty of storing variable value before next command in java

Tags: java, variable-assignment, synchronized, runnable

I am curious if immediately after value assign command like this:

```
a = 5;
```

there is a warranty that the new value has been stored into variable? And if this is different for primitive and other data types? And especially with Runnable objects.

I have run method in MyClass containing:

```
synchronized(this){ 
    while(pleaseWait){ 
        try { System.out.println("sleeping"); wait();} 
        catch (Exception e) {        e.printStackTrace(); } 
    }  
}
```

is other classes i am calling method sleepMe() which contains:

```
synchronized (myclass){
            myclass.pleaseWait = true;
            myclass.notify();
}
```

And the question is, do I have to insert waiting after calling sleepMe, so the instance of MyClass have time to change value of myclass.pleaseWait ?

I have several set methods, where I assing complex objects (objects of objects) to instance of MyClass.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you the two threads are synchronizing on the same object means that the changes made to `pleaseWait` by one thread will be visible to the other thread when it returns from the `wait()` call.  The synchronization (in this case the regaining of the lock on `this` when you return from the `wait()` call) provides the required "happens before" relationship between the two threads to ensure that the update is visible.

So to answer your question:

- Any solution requires one thread to "wait" in some sense.  That's inherent in the problem.
- What you are doing is sufficient.  You don't need to add additional waiting.  The wait/notify mechanism ensures that the thread that does the `wait()` will see an up-to-date copy of the variable ... provided that all changes are made while holding that object lock.
- You can also implement this kind of thing using higher level concurrency classes.
- You could also implement this using a `volatile` and "busy waiting" ... but that would be a really BAD IDEA.

Comment: I forgot to copy-paste notify from my code, adding it to question now